# Exportar BD a hojas de excel

Tags: php, mysql, excel, phpexcel

Excelente Día.

Solicito tu ayuda estoy intentando bajar una BD MySQL a una hoja de Excel, he encontrado un código en Internet y logra bajar la información pero lo muestra con caracteres raros y en desorden total.

**Como les comento el código lo encontré en Internet**

**Crear BD**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `countries` (
```

`id` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `countryCode` char(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `countryName` varchar(45) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `currencyCode` char(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `capital` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `continentName` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=251 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

```
INSERT INTO `countries` (`id`, `countryCode`, `countryName`, `currencyCode`, `capital`, `continentName`) VALUES
(1, 'AD', 'Andorra', 'EUR', 'Andorra la Vella', 'Europe'),
(2, 'AE', 'United Arab Emirates', 'AED', 'Abu Dhabi', 'Asia'),
(3, 'AF', 'Afghanistan', 'AFN', 'Kabul', 'Asia'),
(4, 'AG', 'Antigua and Barbuda', 'XCD', 'St. John''s', 'North America'),
(5, 'AI', 'Anguilla', 'XCD', 'The Valley', 'North America'),
(6, 'AL', 'Albania', 'ALL', 'Tirana', 'Europe'),
(7, 'AM', 'Armenia', 'AMD', 'Yerevan', 'Asia'),
(8, 'AO', 'Angola', 'AOA', 'Luanda', 'Africa'),
(9, 'AQ', 'Antarctica', '', '', 'Antarctica'),
(10, 'AR', 'Argentina', 'ARS', 'Buenos Aires', 'South America'),

ALTER TABLE `countries`
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8" />
      <title>Reporte de excel con PHP y MySQL</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div>
        <h1>REPORTE DE EXCEL CON PHP Y MYSQL</h1>
         <div>
           <a href="exportar.php"> Generar reporte en Excel</a>
        </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

**exportar.php**

```
   <?php
if (PHP_SAPI == 'cli')
    die('Este ejemplo sólo se puede ejecutar desde un navegador Web');

/** Incluye PHPExcel */
require_once 'Librerias/Classes/PHPExcel.php';
// Crear nuevo objeto PHPExcel
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

// Propiedades del documento
$objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setCreator("Obed Alvarado")
                             ->setLastModifiedBy("Obed Alvarado")
                             ->setTitle("Office 2010 XLSX Documento de prueba")
                             ->setSubject("Office 2010 XLSX Documento de prueba")
                             ->setDescription("Documento de prueba para Office 2010 XLSX, generado usando clases de PHP.")
                             ->setKeywords("office 2010 openxml php")
                             ->setCategory("Archivo con resultado de prueba");



// Combino las celdas desde A1 hasta E1
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->mergeCells('A1:E1');

$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
            ->setCellValue('A1', 'REPORTE DE PAISES')
            ->setCellValue('A2', 'CODIGO')
            ->setCellValue('B2', 'NOMBRE')
            ->setCellValue('C2', 'MONEDA')
            ->setCellValue('D2', 'CAPITAL')
            ->setCellValue('E2', 'CONTINENTE');

// Fuente de la primera fila en negrita
$boldArray = array('font' => array('bold' => true,),'alignment' => array('horizontal' => PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER));

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1:E2')->applyFromArray($boldArray);      



//Ancho de las columnas
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('A')->setWidth(8);   
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('B')->setWidth(30);  
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('C')->setWidth(15);  
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('D')->setWidth(20);  
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('E')->setWidth(15);          

/*Extraer datos de MYSQL*/
    # conectare la base de datos
    $con=@mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'pass', 'test');
    if(!$con){
        die("imposible conectarse: ".mysqli_error($con));
    }
    if (@mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        die("Connect failed: ".mysqli_connect_errno()." : ". mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    $sql="SELECT * FROM countries  order by countryName";
    $query=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    $cel=3;//Numero de fila donde empezara a crear  el reporte
    while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
        $countryCode=$row['countryCode'];
        $countryName=$row['countryName'];
        $currencyCode=$row['currencyCode'];
        $capital=$row['capital'];
        $continentName=$row['continentName'];

            $a="A".$cel;
            $b="B".$cel;
            $c="C".$cel;
            $d="D".$cel;
            $e="E".$cel;
            // Agregar datos
            $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
            ->setCellValue($a, $countryCode)
            ->setCellValue($b, $countryName)
            ->setCellValue($c, $currencyCode)
            ->setCellValue($d, $capital)
            ->setCellValue($e, $continentName);

    $cel+=1;
    }

/*Fin extracion de datos MYSQL*/
$rango="A2:$e";
$styleArray = array('font' => array( 'name' => 'Arial','size' => 10),
'borders'=>array('allborders'=>array('style'=> PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_THIN,'color'=>array('argb' => 'FFF')))
);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($rango)->applyFromArray($styleArray);
// Cambiar el nombre de hoja de cálculo
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Reporte de paises');


// Establecer índice de hoja activa a la primera hoja , por lo que Excel abre esto como la primera hoja
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);


// Redirigir la salida al navegador web de un cliente ( Excel5 )
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="reporte.xls"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
// Si usted está sirviendo a IE 9 , a continuación, puede ser necesaria la siguiente
header('Cache-Control: max-age=1');

// Si usted está sirviendo a IE a través de SSL , a continuación, puede ser necesaria la siguiente
header ('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT'); // Date in the past
header ('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s').' GMT'); // always modified
header ('Cache-Control: cache, must-revalidate'); // HTTP/1.1
header ('Pragma: public'); // HTTP/1.0

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
exit;
```

Me genera el archivo y baja la información pero la muestra de la siguiente forma:

[image: Con carácteres raros]

Agradezco su atención

Comment: Intenta agregando el siguiente header: header("Content-Type:   application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=utf-8");

Comment: Hola @CésarAlejandroM el la parte final de exportar.php ? En donde se encuentran los demás header

Comment: Reemplazarlo por header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');

Comment: Una vez tuve el problema al generar un csv, tras buscar encontré algo llamado utf-8 bom; Realmente no profundicé en ello, pero se arregló mi problema de codificación que no pudo ser resuelto por los headers.

 fprintf($output_file, chr(0xEF).chr(0xBB).chr(0xBF));

$output_file es la ruta(absoluta) al fichero, incluyendo su nombre y extensión, prueba con ello luego que guardas el fichero o cuando lo generas, antes de agregar las filas.

Comment: Lo intentare por que aunque he cambiado el header como me has indicado el encabezado de la hoja de excel me sigue generando carácteres raros

Answer (score 0):

Prueba usando codificación utf8 a las variables.

```
utf8_encode ( string $data )
```

ejemplo:

```
->setCellValue($a,  utf8_encode ( $countryCode) )
```

Comment: Hola @Daniel Pernia lo he intentado, aunque sabes ya checando con más detalle lo de CHARSET, En la creación de mi BD le coloque utf8 lo ha tomando como uft8_general_ci, la verdad desconozco si esto me este generando el error